# Memory leak using django channels, apscheduler, and google oauth2client

Tags: python, django, google-oauth, apscheduler, django-channels

My code pulls data from [Google Analytics](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_oauth) every X seconds and pushes it to a WebSocket frontend via [Django Channels](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). I'm using an [apscheduler BackgroundScheduler](http://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/schedulers/background.html#apscheduler.schedulers.background.BackgroundScheduler) to run the *tick* function on the specified interval. But when I run this, the memory usage grows at a pretty constant rate even if all I do is authorize the oauth API. Example code from consumers.py:

```
from channels.sessions import channel_session
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
from oauth2client import transport
from apiclient.discovery import build

scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()

def tick(group_id):
    user = GoogleUser.objects.all()[0]
    # gets DjangoORMStorage instance
    credentials = get_credentials(user).get() 

    # THESE TWO LINES SEEM TO CAUSE THE MEMORY LEAK
    oauth_http = credentials.authorize(transport.get_http_object())
    analytics = build('analytics', 'v3', http=oauth_http)

@channel_session
def ws_connect(message):
    # accept socket connection and add channel to group
    message.reply_channel.send({"accept": True})

    # add channel to websocket channel group
    redis_group = Group(group_id, channel_layer=None)
    redis_group.add(message.reply_channel)

    # schedule job
    scheduler.add_job(tick, 'interval', id=slug, kwargs={
        'group_id': group_id,
    }, seconds=settings.INTERVAL)
    scheduler.start()
```